# Кастомизация иконок легенды графика highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Как можно поменять иконку легенды на другую? 
Она не меняется если тип графика выбран area.

```
  chart: {
              type: 'area',
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Например вот тут можно поменять тип на area и иконки в легенде станут кружочками.

```
chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

Comment: на что вы его хотите поменять то?

Comment: Например на картинку.

Comment: похоже весьма печально с этим. можно поменять маркеры точек на картинки, они же будут использоваться в легенд (http://jsfiddle.net/0pbygt7c/) или (http://jsfiddle.net/mq1a7qsh/68/)

можно переопределить функцию рисования (http://jsfiddle.net/Lcwawocg/)

либо назначить ей функцию из другого типа серий. 
в общем задача не тривильаная. Если в легенду в labelFormatter вернуть картинку, то при использовании useHTML, картинки нет.